# How to integrate Angular into a WordPress plugin

Tags: wordpress, angular

How can we integrate a Angular project (Angular2) into a WordPress plugin that will be pushed into official WP repository? What dependency should be added?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can give your first try with https://1fix.io/blog/2014/11/05/angularjs-json-api-wp-theme/

In a similar way we can implement in wp plugin as well.

Comment: Dear @Rafin, thanks for your answer, however I already did some of those "AngularJS" toto, but it looks like it will be a bit different for "Angular (2)"